# Rendering a screen within a game world in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 3d world the player can interact, I'm wanting the player to pick up a gameboy and play a game on the gameboy.

I'm wondering how I can render another 'game' on the gameboy the player can play with while still being in the world, meaning it's a game in a game. I tried doing this with Cameras, but I'm stuck as I don't seem to understand the core concept behind rendering a game there. I know I could render a canvas using UGUI but I don't think I can make a physics based game on UGUI?

Would love some help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering complete camera view(16:9) onto a texture in Unity3d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996534/rendering-complete-camera-view169-onto-a-texture-in-unity3d)

Comment: Also, it would have been nice if you had some code examples to show what you tried, or maybe explain what steps you had taken already to try to solve your problem.

Comment: No it's not a duplicate

Comment: @Payedimaunt Well, it's not necessarily a duplicate, but it could very well lead to a solution OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need a [Render Texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html). And the game scene of the gameboy should be the same scene as your main game, it just has to show another location in the world.

Try to implement it, and come back if you can't figure out how to implement something.