# Unity: Create a texture from Terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-terrain

I have a procedural generated `Terrain`, based on `Unity's Terrain System`.

Now i want a `Map` from the `Terrain`, not a minimap but a full map, that is saved as a `2D Texture`.

First i thought of a `RenderTexture`, but if i take a `Camera` to catch the whole `Terrain`, the result depends on the resolution aspect, and i also have problems cause the `width` of the `Terrain` is `3.2x` the `length`.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: I would set up an orthographic camera over the terrain whose width and height matches the terrain, and you can set the resolution of the texture however you please

Comment: @Ruzihm i tried that, but if the screens aspect ratio changes, the width and height don't match the terrain anymore. Is is somehow possible to set up a orthographic camera so that it got fix values that don't change with the resolution?

Comment: yep! Part of "set up an orthographic camera over the terrain whose width and height matches the terrain" includes setting the aspect ratio of that camera. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59001943/1092820) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make a new camera and place it over the terrain.
2. Make sure it is in orthographic mode
3. Set the `camera.aspect` field to `terrainData.size.x / terrainData.size.z`
4. Set the `camera.orthographicSize` field to `terrainData.size.z/2f`
5. Make sure the camera frame is oriented with the terrain's axes. Something along the lines of `cam.transform.LookAt(terrain.GetPosition(), terrain.transform.forward);` will do the trick.

Then, you should be able to create a `RenderTexture` with the pixel resolution you'd like (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32998473/1092820) by Rafal Wiliński):

```
int resHeight = 1000;
int resWidth = Mathf.RoundToInt(resHeight * camera.aspect);

RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
camera.targetTexture = rt; //Create new renderTexture and assign to camera
Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false); //Create new texture

camera.Render();

RenderTexture.active = rt;
screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0); //Apply pixels from camera onto Texture2D

camera.targetTexture = null;
RenderTexture.active = null; //Clean
Destroy(rt); //Free memory
```

then, your terrain would be captured in `screenshot`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Just two things, you need to set the camera.aspect to "terrainData.size.x / terrainData.size.z" and the camera.orthographicSize to "terrainData.size.z / 2f".